# Trying to have macro filter everything in a column and save individual workbooks per sorted item in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros, save

I have a report that is sorted by column C.  I need to save individual workbooks based off of each item from column C.  There are headers in row 1.

Below is the code that I believe should work but isn't.  I am also unsure how to site the specifc folder to save it to.

```
 If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
  fname = Range("C2")
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
 End If
```

Comment: Check out [WorkBook.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) you'll want to set the folder to save it into in the filename parameter. Also I may be wrong on this but you might be setting the value of `fname` improperly, I believe it should be `fname = Range("C2").value`

Comment: In this case `fname` should be entire path, including directory, file name and file extension. It should be declared as string. Also as TyleBedo has mentioned, use `fname = Range("C2").value` or `fname = Range("C2").value2`. Try to be more specific, not working can have many outcomes, from code error (which place?) to executing all lines, but not doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  When debugging it highlights the line
If Target.Address = ""$C$2" Then

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro which will handle targeting cells in a sheet. It must be placed into this specific sheet's code. Example of fname value which is stored in C2 cell is:
C:\Users\Taisho\Desktop\example.xlsx
The reason why your macro was not working is probably not assigning variable type to `Target`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim fname As String    

If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    fname = Range("C2").value2
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
End If

End Sub
```